# Creating dummy models via Django Management Commands

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-1.11, django-management-command

I'm trying to write a script for Custom Django Management Commands. The script is to create orders (a model) each with a random amount of servers between 1 to 10 assigned to it. So far I have:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'etc...'

def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('dummy-orders', type=int, help='Number of dummy-orders to create')
    parser.add_argument('servers-min', type=int, help='Minimum random amount of servers')
    parser.add_argument('servers-max', type=int, help='Maximum random amount of servers (max=10)')

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    dummy_orders = options['dummy-orders']
    servers_min = options['servers-min']
    servers_max = options['servers-max']

    assert dummy_orders <= 3000
    self.check_input_integers(servers_min, servers_max, 'Servers')

    for i in range(dummy_orders):
        servers_random = randint(servers_min, servers_max)
        #test = Order.objects.create(servers_num=servers_random)
        model = Order
        #model = Order(servers_num=servers_random)
        #user = Order.objects.get_or_create()
        print(model)
```

Basically, each order is also to have a random number of servers associated with this. There was originally no `servers_num` field, which I had to add in models. The problem I face is just how to simply iterate over the `range(dummy_orders)` and to assign the random number of servers to it. Any ideas? Since this is aimed for testing purposes only, I'd expect I'd have to somehow delete all these new entries too?

Answer (score 0):

Simple really, I just created an model object like normal e.g. (`model = DummyOrder(servers_num=servers_random, luns_num=luns_random)`). That seemed to suffice for what was required.